# Changing enter and tab

Tags: keyboard

I would like to make enter key act as tab and tab key act as enter in my keyboard, and also backspace to (`) and shift-backspace to (~).
I would also like to change Left, Down, Up and Right to F1, F2, F3, F4.

Answer (score 0):

There are two built-in command that you can use: `xev` and `xmodmap`.

Both command line applications are available by default, so there is no need to install additional software.

Xev "creates a window and then asks the X server to send it events whenever anything happens to the window (such as it being moved, resized, typed in, clicked in, etc.)." [xev man page](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/xev.1.html)

xmodmap is a "program is used to edit and display the keyboard modifier map and keymap table that are used by client applications to convert event keycodes into keysyms." [xmodmap man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html)

And Also there are some applications that do this for you. One of them is **xbindkeys**

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Xbindkeys is a very versatile program that lets you remap keys very easily. It uses a config file, my default located in your home directory, to change key bindings into certain commands.

For more information please go to [this site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys).

Comment: I saw that I can call a command, but how would I change a key for another???